# Function only works when there is a println() statement at the end of each iteration

Tags: julia, graph-theory

I'm trying to implement a 3-clique (triangle) finding algorithm from a [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0d19/245a27bc65a87a8014d5b8a66fb514c8ff0b.pdf?_ga=2.233619993.688720620.1595866763-138298936.1592504746) (p. 212-213) in Julia, but I'm running into a problem with the code

```
function find_triangle(graph::AdjacencyListGraphs)

    new_graph = deepcopy(graph)
    sort!(new_graph.edges, by=x->new_graph.D[x], rev=true)
    cliques = Vector{Vector{Int64}}()
    marked_nodes = Set()

    for i in 1:new_graph.n - 2
        cur = new_graph.edges[new_graph.edges.keys[1]]

        # mark vertices adjacent to i
        for j in 1:length(cur)
            push!(marked_nodes,cur[j])
        end

        # search in marked nodes
        for j in 1:length(cur)
            u = cur[j]
            for w in new_graph.edges[u]
                if w in marked_nodes
                    cur_clique = [new_graph.edges.keys[1], u, w]
                    push!(cliques, cur_clique)
                end
            delete!(marked_nodes, u)
            end
        end

        # delete node
        for key in new_graph.edges.keys
            filter!(x->x≠new_graph.edges.keys[1],new_graph.edges[key])
        end
        delete!(new_graph.edges, new_graph.edges.keys[1])

        # this println() call is currently used to prevent an unknown error. Not sure why, but this fixes it
        println(new_graph)
    end

    return cliques
end
```

The input to the function is the following

```
nodes = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

edges = OrderedDict{Int64, Vector{Int64}}()
edges[1] = [2,3,5]
edges[2] = [1,3,4,6]
edges[3] = [1,2,4,6]
edges[4] = [2,3,5,6]
edges[5] = [1,4]
edges[6] = [2,3,4]

degrees = [3,4,4,4,2,3]
graph = AdjacencyListGraphs(nodes, 6, 10, degrees, edges)
cliques = find_triangle(graph)
```

And the type definition for the graph is as follows:

```
mutable struct AdjacencyListGraphs{Int64}
    vals::Vector{Int64} # vertex list
    n::Int64 # number of vertices
    m::Int64 # number of edges
    D::Vector{Int64} # degree sequence
    edges::OrderedDict{Int64, Vector{Int64}} # adjacency list
end
```

The function runs properly if I include the println() statement, but if I remove just that statement, I run into the following bug

```
ERROR: LoadError: KeyError: key 2 not found
```

The issue to me looks like an error in the deletion of a node, and someohow the println() statement fixes it. The reason why I need to fix this is because I'm trying to run the code on a much bigger graph with about a million triangles, but the println() call at each step is literally crashing my computer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thank you!

Comment: is `AdjacencyListGraphs` a user defined type? Can you please share the code for it

Comment: Just added more information to the post. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 5):

The reason of the problem is that you use `keys` field of `OrderedDict` which is private. You should use accessor function e.g. like this:

```
function find_triangle(graph::AdjacencyListGraphs)

    new_graph = deepcopy(graph)
    sort!(new_graph.edges, by=x->new_graph.D[x], rev=true)
    cliques = Vector{Vector{Int64}}()
    marked_nodes = Set()

    for i in 1:new_graph.n - 2
        curk = first(keys(new_graph.edges))
        cur = new_graph.edges[curk]

        # mark vertices adjacent to i
        for j in 1:length(cur)
            push!(marked_nodes,cur[j])
        end

        # search in marked nodes
        for j in 1:length(cur)
            u = cur[j]
            for w in new_graph.edges[u]
                if w in marked_nodes
                    cur_clique = [curk, u, w]
                    push!(cliques, cur_clique)
                end
            delete!(marked_nodes, u)
            end
        end

        # delete node
        for key in new_graph.edges.keys
            filter!(x->x≠curk,new_graph.edges[key])
        end
        delete!(new_graph.edges, curk)

        # this println() call is currently used to prevent an unknown error. Not sure why, but this fixes it
   #     println(new_graph)
    end

    return cliques
end
```

The reason for the problem is that you delete keys in the dictionary, but not call `rehash!` on it. Incidentally `rehash!` is called when you call `println` because it calls `iterate` which in turn calls `rehash!`. So this would work:

```
function find_triangle(graph::AdjacencyListGraphs)

    new_graph = deepcopy(graph)
    sort!(new_graph.edges, by=x->new_graph.D[x], rev=true)
    cliques = Vector{Vector{Int64}}()
    marked_nodes = Set()

    for i in 1:new_graph.n - 2
        DataStructures.OrderedCollections.rehash!(new_graph.edges)
        cur = new_graph.edges[new_graph.edges.keys[1]]

        # mark vertices adjacent to i
        for j in 1:length(cur)
            push!(marked_nodes,cur[j])
        end

        # search in marked nodes
        for j in 1:length(cur)
            u = cur[j]
            for w in new_graph.edges[u]
                if w in marked_nodes
                    cur_clique = [new_graph.edges.keys[1], u, w]
                    push!(cliques, cur_clique)
                end
            delete!(marked_nodes, u)
            end
        end

        # delete node
        for key in new_graph.edges.keys
            filter!(x->x≠new_graph.edges.keys[1],new_graph.edges[key])
        end
        delete!(new_graph.edges, new_graph.edges.keys[1])

        # this println() call is currently used to prevent an unknown error. Not sure why, but this fixes it
        #println(new_graph)
    end

    return cliques
end
```

but you should not write code like this, but rather use public API.

Comment: Can you please explain how it is affected by `println`

Comment: Yesterday, during JuliaCon2020 I tried to explain during https://live.juliacon.org/talk/8SFYHK (the advanced part) how one can quickly find a root cause of such problems.

Comment: I will look it up. much needed resource

Comment: It was incidentally on my list of workshops to attend. But yesterday was a busy day

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering, but this helps a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some body overwrote `println` or `show` for that custom type `AdjacencyListGraphs`, is the only reason I cuold find for a `println` to change the state of the code!.